# How to send request to nearby drivers in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

how can I send request to nearby drivers what is the algorithm can please anyone guide me I am making ridesharing app.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by splitting areas into **topics** depending on location and subscribe users to this topics so they will be able to receive the correct notifications.

[Here you can see the how with FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging)

Answer (score 0):

i guess this is what you are looking for (in-depth explanation with code)-

[Build Your Own Uber/Lyft App with Geolocation Tracking](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/build-your-own-uber-lyft-app-geolocation-tracking-android/)

Comment: hit the upvote button, if it answers your question !